# How do I validate that at least one of these radio buttons has been selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have tried everything I can think of to validate these radio buttons using Javascript and/or JQuery. Nothing is working. Here is my form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("NextPage", "AccountsFinance", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div class="row Question">
    <h2>@Model.Question</h2>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <table cellspacing="10">
        <tr>
            @foreach (string answer in Model.Answers)
            {
                <td><input id="rad" type="radio" name="answer" value="@answer" /><span>@answer</span></td>
            }
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="row footerButtons">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="Previous" value="Back" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="NextPage" value="Next" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">&nbsp;</div>
</div>a
}
```

I don't know whether the problem is that I end up having multiple inputs with the same id, or because I am using a HtmlHelper form. I have tried numerous Stack Overflow solutions including everything from inline javascript to using for loops and nothing works. For example, using my current attempt:

```
function myFunction() {
    var chx = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < chx.length; i++) {
        if (chx[i].type == 'radio' && !chx[i].checked) {
            alert("nope");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }

    }
};
```

It doesn't matter whether I click a radio button or not, I always get the `alert("nope");` appearing. What is going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you use **document.getElementById('rad')** Instead **getElementsByTagName**

Comment: *having multiple inputs with the same id* means your HTML is **invalid**. you should never have multiple items with the same id

Comment: @Liam then we can use unique class name for all radio buttons and get by this **document.getElementsByClassName("example")**

Comment: what is your problem. what are you going to do with the validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off don't use the same id multiple times, this invalidates your HTML!

If you then want to check if only one is checked you can do this in pretty much one line

```
function myFunction() {
  if ($('input[name="answer"]:checked').length === 1)
  {
     console.log('only one checked');
  }
};
```

or without the logging

```
function myFunction() {
  return $('input[name="answer"]:checked').length === 1;
};
```

FYI, if they all have the same name and are radio's then you can only check one at most anyway. So there is no need to check for > 1

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not use an id attribute as you'll end having a lot of them on the page.
2. Use `$("input[type='radio']")` to fetch all the radio inputs from the page
3. Store the result of the fetching on an array and then iterate trough it and see if it's checked
4. You could further customize the Jquery from point 3 to get only the unchecked or checked radio buttons.

example:

```
function myFunction() {
    var radios = $("input[type='radio']");
    for( i = 0; i < radios.length; i++ ) {
        if( radios[i].checked ) {
            return true
        } else {
          return false;
         }

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The OP wants a true/false value, which your not returning.

Comment: Except when it returns null?

Answer (score -1):

You can use below jQuery code to validate the Radio button, there is nothing wrong with your html. Just use below code.

```
$(function(){
    if($("input:radio:checked").length() <= 0){
       alert('Nope')
    }
    else{
       alert('Yup')
    }
})
```

Comment: [Size() is deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/size/) and should no longer be used

Comment: ...should use length. This is likely going to be removed from later versions of jquery.

Comment: so.....We agree...good.....Do you intend to edit your answer??...as it's wrong right now. We both agree on that don't we?